# Architecture of CNN to accept 2 sets of inputs

Tags: tensorflow

There are multiple examples how to build Tensorflow model to recognise cats and dogs from images. Now suppose I have audio associated with each picture and train separate network to recognise cats and dogs by sound.

I want to feed predictions of both networks into another layer to combine results and increase final prediction success rate.

How should my model look like?

Answer (score 0):

Create two neural networks, that given a pair image-audio, you input each value to its corresponding net.

After the convolution steps or whatever you want to use, proceed as you would do with a normal CNN, in the last step before passing data to a FNN, when you flatten the data, do the same with the output of the audio NN.

So, as an example, if the output of the images one (flattened) has shape `2048` and the audio `4096` just append these two and make first layer of the FNN to have the sum of these shapes = `6144`.

Comment: I cant imagine why this would work. the convoluted output values might be vastly different between audio and video. say one is 0..10 and other -1000 to 1000 or whatever. I am just speculating.. I don't see theoretical base for what you are saying. Can you elaborate please?